# Mmap : keep track of accessed regions

Tags: c, linux, mmap

### Context :

Working on a text file.
Linux, debian 64bits.
C99-C11

### Need :

Keep track of the opened indexes of that file.
E.g :

I open the index 65, then 235, then 12, then 1024 to read the letter.
I wish to be able to keep track of those index like that [12,65,235,1024].

I read the kernel keeps a structure but..

#### The absence of a malloc'd array in the code to keep track is a constraint.

Why ? to see how possible / impracticable it is.

The system (obviously?) keeps a track for me already, right ?

### Question :

Can the kernel help me to keep track of the opened indexes of the mmap'd file (and if possible in sorted) to avoid a malloc'd index in the code ?

## EDIT:

It is not an index file. It is a basic text file with some text in it. I want to keep track of the accessed bytes and I don't want to use an array for it if the kernel already knows which bytes have been loaded / accessed.

Comment: Are these indexes files? Are you talking about records in a file?  If you are using mmap, the kernel won't do you much good unless the data you are indexing is the size of the pages that mmap uses, which is likely 4k.

Comment: I update the question to make it clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When discussing "keeping track" of anything, the important question is "What's the primary key?"/"How do you intend to access it?".

The kernel only needs to know that "address A has a mapping of file X, offset Y, length Z". It has no need to waste resources on knowing where file X is mapped. Most likely the only way the kernel knows that a file is mapped anywhere is a reference count that someone is using that file, it probably doesn't even know if those are mmap:s or just open file descriptors.

In fact, when a file is forcibly invalidated (like on unmount), it's implemented by just replacing the file object with an invalid file object rather than keeping track of mappings and destroying them (this is 10 years old information in Linux, it might have changed since then, I just know for sure other operating systems still work like that).

So to answer your question: the kernel probably doesn't care about knowing what you need to know. You need to do it yourself. Especially if you want to be portable at all.

Comment: So, when asking for virtual memory to mmap a file, there is no way to know which part of the file is lazily loaded into ram ?

Comment: To begin with, there's no way of asking the kernel (unless you parse things in /proc, but that's too slow for any practical use). My point is that even if there was a way, the kernel only knows "what is mapped at this address", not "which address maps this part".